# Open data community ideation tools?

Tags: tool-request

Which communities are doing a good job on capturing community ideas around open gov / civic technology / policy improvements?

Additional Questions?

- If you were to break out ideation categories, how would you define
  these realms?
- Suggestions on ways to improve these ideation
  tools?

Examples of CfA Brigade Ideation tools...

- NYC: [betaNYC's project board](http://betanyc.ideascale.com),
- Oakland: [Open Oakland](http://openoakland.uservoice.com/),
- [Hampton Roads](https://c4hrva.uservoice.com/forums/103669-code-for-hampton-roads) (dead link, [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141016023505/http://c4hrva.uservoice.com:80/forums/103669-code-for-hampton-roads)),
- [San Diego](http://c4sd.uservoice.com/) (dead link, [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219084333/http://c4sd.uservoice.com:80/)),
- Code For America's Brigade: [The Great American Civic Hack](http://cfabrigade.ideascale.com/).

General realms of ideation...

- Software Project Ideas, Things that can be worked on a hacknight, et. al.
- Data Set Ideas, Ideas for data sets, etc.
- Policy Improvement Ideas, Ideas on how to improve legislation or policy.
- Open Government Ideas, Catch all for other things.

Other examples:

- [Change By US](http://nyc.changeby.us/#start) (dead link, [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221113105/http://nyc.changeby.us/#start)),
- [ioby](https://ioby.org/),
- [OpenIDEO](https://www.openideo.com/),
- [NYC BigApps](https://www.bigapps.nyc/),
- [NYC BigApps Ideas](https://bigappsideas.devpost.com/),
- [NY Tech Meetup](https://nytechmeetup.ideascale.com/a/index).

Answer (score 2):

Another avenue I'd offer for your consideration is the "Data Jam" model of generating great Ideations and then the companion "Datapalooza" showcase for spurring creation of actual products.  [Boston](http://boston.cleanwebhack.com/wp/?page_id=448) and the NC [Research Triangle](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwksgPYNPKn9dFdsd2kzY0pabzA/edit) are in the middle of such an experiment.

Also, here is a [draft handbook](https://hackpad.com/Datapalooza-the-how-to-guide-for-empowering-innovators-WWi6fyHOrA3) for how anyone familiar with a Hackathon can host their own Data Jams and Datapaloozas.

Answer (score 2):

Despite our tool approach being cited above (thanks @noneck), for us in Oakland the best tool is still an actual process of connecting with people with actual issues and ideas in person and listening. Not to be facetious at all, but for all the feedback and ideas I've seen on MindMixer and other platforms, the strongest ideas have happened in person. So perhaps CityCamp is the tool of choice for us?